# Git config file results in different behavior between two similar environments

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

I have two Linux servers with Ubuntu v 16.04.2 LTS - one for development/testing and the other for production.  The .git/config files in both are structure similarly structured:

Production .git/config file:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = git@bitbucket.org:gt/project.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Development .git/config file:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = git@bitbucket.org:gt/project.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

I'm able to pull code from my respository in the development server using:

```
sudo git pull git@bitbucket.org:gt/project.git master
```

When I use the same command to pull code into the production server, I get the following error message:

```
From bitbucket.org:gt/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@prod.(none)')
```

While I understand I likely need to change my .git/config file for the production server, why is it that I'm able to successfully pull code into my development server which has an identical .git/config file?  What should I be looking for as a difference between my production and development servers to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Git has additional config files (see [1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES)). Most likely the production settings for `user.name` and `user.email` are in `~root/.gitconfig` and these setting are missing in your own user configuration (aka. `--global`).

You can also check where a setting is stored:

```
git config --show-origin --get-all user.name
```

Comment: @ A.H. - no addition git related config files as far as I can tell (looked for the other three possible files mentioned in the git documentation).  Somehow, the development server works just fine, but having issues on the production server.

Comment: @user6860460 I have updated the answer to show the location the config is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You're running:

> sudo git pull git@bitbucket.org:gt/project.git master

A git *pull* is a combination of a *fetch* to bring the remote branch information and the commits into the local repository, and a *merge* to merge those changes from the remote into the local branch.

If there haven't been any changes locally, then this should result in a *fast-forward* merge, which isn't actually a "merge" at all.  There's no local changes that need included, so instead of trying to combine changes from two different branches, git can simply update the local branch pointer to the remote's commit.

However, if you *do* have local changes, then they actually do need to be merged with the remote changes.  The results will be committed as a merge commit.

If you don't have a `user.name` or `user.email` setting configured, the merge cannot proceed and you will see this error message, since that information is needed to create the merge commit.

You can run `git log` to see what's been committed on the production server.  Hotfix in production perhaps?

Ensure that the production change is included in the remote, or you can obliterate those changes entirely and force an update to the remote with `git reset --hard origin/master`.